# Sencha Touch focuses textfield in overlay on list disclose

Tags: focus, sencha-touch-2, overlay, disclosure

I have an odd issue with Sencha Touch 2. I have a list with disclosure on, when tapping the disclosure icon, I open an overlay, and load some data into the form it contains. All is well up until this point.

The odd problem I am experiencing is, that when the overlay opens, if the disclosure icon in the now underlying list is in a spot where a textfield is positioned in the overlay, it gets focused and opens the keyboard and so on.

This is only a problem on iPad, it doesn't occur on my desktop machine, neither in Chrome or in Safari on a Windows 8 system.

I hope the explanation is clear enough, if not, I will do my best to describe the situation further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always have the same problem which I usually solve like this:

Let's say the function handling the disclosure on your list is this one:

```
onListDisclose: function (list, record, target, index, e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  ...
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: _Unfortunately that didn't do any difference, very good suggestion though!_

Nevermind me, I had the wrong file open when I tested your suggestion. It seems to have solved the problem.

Thansk a bunch, TDeBailleul. :)